# Existence of a universal $0$-cycle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, algebraic-cycles

For a smooth (complex) projective surface $S$ with non trivial Albanese variety, are there simple conditions for the existence a universal codimension $2$ cycle i.e. a $Z\in \mathrm{CH}^2(Alb(S)\times S)$ such that the induced morphism $Alb(S)\rightarrow Alb(S)$ is the identity?

Comment: Do you want sufficient conditions?  It is true if $S$ is a product of curves whose Jacobians share no nontrivial factors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the example. Yes, I would like sufficient conditions or some references to the study of instances (other than your example) of this property.

Comment: I guess the hypothesis about common factors is superfluous.  Sorry about that.